# Tensorflow: Dynamic external value in custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, loss-function

I want to train a model with a custom loss function. To weight the calculated loss inside the function I want to use an external value. This value relates to the label (with same shape), but is not a part of the labels datasets - so it is something like an "hidden relation" organized in an array.

Pseudocode of the loss function I need looks like this:

```py
def custom_loss(hidden_relation[i]):
  def loss(y_true, y_pred)
    if y_true == y_pred:
      p_loss = <something math with y_true, y_pred, hidden_relation[i]>
      return p_loss
    else:
      p_loss = <something other math with y_true, y_pred, hidden_relation[i]>
      return p_loss
  return loss
```

My problem is the index i. Inside the loss function `y_true` and `y_pred` are not given as something like `y_true = [[label],[i]]` and `y_pred = [[prediction],[i]]`. So how can I know which i'th row from label datasets is used for this training iteration? (My batch size is 1.)

Some more background: My application is a time series forecasting. Parallel to the time series, there is a list of delayed events. If any such event occurs, this leads to higher or lower values in the time series (like a feedback loop).
I think that patterns in the time series can predict these (delayed) events. So I would like to further penalize the model if it misses these patterns, because this leads to bad predictions. On the other hand, if a delayed event does not occur it doesn't matter, no extra penalty necessary.
When training on historical data, I know if a prediction coincides with an event. In reality, I do not have this additional information, though. So I can not use the event list for the input labels since it doesn't exist (yet).

Thank you for your help!

Best
hippo

Comment: You can just format the labels to the format `y_true = [[label],[i]]` and then pass them to `fit`.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But how to excluded `i` from the prediction?

Comment: the predictions depend on the output of your model?

Comment: I tried to describe it better and add "Some more background" in the question above.

Comment: can't you use `sample_weights` for this?

Comment: This solves my problem. I did not have the fit parameter `sample_weights` in mind.
Thanks for the support!